# Datatables.net date display format

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatables.net jquery plugin and populating the data through asp.net mvc4.

One of my columns is a date format. I'm interested in changing the format of how it is displayed but not changing the type of the column from date to string.

I'm currently using default initialization:

```
$('#data-table').dataTable();
```

My 4th column is a date "Created Date" and is currently displayed as "7/07/2013 9:38:11 p.m."
I would like it to be displayed as either "7/07/2013" or "7 Jul 2013".

I thought this was a relatively easy task but haven't been able to find the answer I'm after.

I'd like to avoid additional plugins if possible.
Is there a simple way that I'm missing?

Comment: It's [recommended to omit "Thanks" lines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/172431) and the `datatables` tags are [not recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128285/172431).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. Using how it renders I can manipulate the way the date is displayed to anyway I want.

```
$('#data-table').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 
            "aTargets": [0], 
            "bSearchable": false, 
            "sType": 'date',
            "fnRender": function ( oObj ) {
                var javascriptDate = new Date(oObj.aData[0]);
                javascriptDate = javascriptDate.getDate()+"/"+(javascriptDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+javascriptDate.getFullYear();
                return "<div class='date'>"+javascriptDate+"<div>";
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I hope this will be useful to others...

Comment: Does it change the 4th column as you stated in question or 0th as in your answer?

Comment: @zygimantus, does it matter? The answer (should) give you an understanding of how you can deal with dates, regardless of which column number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a nullable DateTime? you'll want to use a different rendering function:

```
        $('#users-tbl').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { "data": "ID", "visible" : false},

            {"data": "MyDateField",
             "type": "date ",
             "render":function (value) {
                 if (value === null) return "";

                  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                  var results = pattern.exec(value);
                  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));

                  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();}
            }
        ]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether using a legacy version of the plugin or the latest, the render function is the way to go.  From that point it becomes a question not so much of datatables (which doesn't do any formatting) and how to format a date in JavaScript.

For that, I'd recommend the excellent [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/) (rock solid, ~30k stars on github, 100k+ unit tests; pretty much the go-to for dealing with time in js).